# Bootstrap dropdown menu with image and long text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a dropdown menu with Bootstrap, with images and a long text, that may have to be word-wrapped to be inside a width of 500px

I tried suggestions like this:

```
.dropdown-menu {
    width: 500px;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Here is my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/azu0zwrr/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add :

```
overflow: hidden;
```

---

```css
.dropdown-menu li{
  width: 500px; white-space: normal;overflow: hidden;
}
.img-thumbnail {
  width:75px;height:75px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="btn-group"><button aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg dropdown-toggle" type="button">Selecione um produto&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b class="caret"></b></button><ul class="dropdown-menu"><li><a><img class="img-thumbnail hidden-xs" src="http://www.extra-imagens.com.br/Control/ArquivoExibir.aspx?IdArquivo=107393037">&nbsp;&nbsp;Tablet Multilaser ML Supra Quad Core com Tela 7”, 8GB, Wi-Fi, Android 4.4, Suporte à Modem 3G e Processador Quad Core - Rosa</a></li><li><a><img class="img-thumbnail hidden-xs" src="http://www.extra-imagens.com.br/Control/ArquivoExibir.aspx?IdArquivo=107392987">&nbsp;&nbsp;Tablet Multilaser ML Supra Quad Core com Tela 7”, 8GB, Wi-Fi, Android 4.4, Suporte à Modem 3G e Processador Quad Core - Branco</a></li></ul></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css:

```
.dropdown-menu li a {
word-wrap: break-word;
white-space: normal;
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1usvrs3e/

Comment: you probably want to work more on the styling, but this will at least wrap your list item links

Answer (score 0):

```
 Check this out This should be working for you 

     <li ><a><p style="word-wrap: break-word;" ><img class="img-thumbnail hidden-xs" src="http://www.extra-imagens.com.br/Control/ArquivoExibir.aspx?IdArquivo=107393037">&nbsp;&nbsp;Tablet Multilaser ML Supra Quad Core com Tela 7”, 8GB, Wi-Fi, Android 4.4, Suporte à Modem 3G e Processador Quad Core - RosaaSdad</a></p></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? I changed the width on both style tags to auto.

```
.dropdown-menu {
   width: auto; white-space: normal;
}
.img-thumbnail {
   width:auto;height:75px;
}
```